# In a Clojure/ClojureScript project, what are the advantages of declaring dependencies on a `deps.edn` file instead of using `shadow-cljs.edn`?

Tags: clojure, dependency-management, clojurescript, leiningen, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Currently, the project uses `project.clj` and `shadow-cljs.edn` to declare dependencies.

There is a discussion about changing things so that:

1 - We would start using a `lein` plug-in called [lein-tools-deps](https://github.com/RickMoynihan/lein-tools-deps)

2 - Also, we would tweak `shadow-cljs.edn` file so that the dependencies would be removed and the file only indicate:

```clj
:dependencies true
```

3 - Finally, we would create a new `deps.edn` file holding all the dependencies.

It is not totally clear the advantages of this process.

I can see one: instead of declaring dependencies on `shadow-cljs.edn` *and* on `project.clj` they would be in a single file: `deps.edn`.

Is there another benefit of having dependency declaration via `deps.edn` instead of using `shadow-cljs.edn` and `project.clj` via `:dependencies`?

For instance, would this affect the use of Maven packages hosted on GitHub packages? Is `deps.edn` better for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deps.edn` has the benefit that it supports direct git dependencies (ie. `:git/url`), as well as an easy mechanism for local dependencies (ie. `:local/root`). It is also more modern and becoming the "default".

`shadow-cljs.edn` has no support for these features, `project.clj` has some via plugins or other mechanism (eg. `checkouts`).

So, if you want those features it make sense to use `deps.edn`. However, depending on how complex your project is that might not be an easy switch.

`shadow-cljs` ultimately doesn't care how you manage your dependencies, but if you move things out of `shadow-cljs.edn` you are taking "power" away from it. If managed via `shadow-cljs.edn` it tries to prevent certain mistakes (eg. dependency conflicts), it can't do that when running via `deps.edn`. So, you'll have to sort those out manually potentially. It may just work, really depends on your project.

Comment: Thank you. What about *private* Maven packages hosted on GitHub Packages? Can shadow-cljs handle them?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. If you can do it with lein project.clj, then it should work with shadow-cljs. Assuming its done via the `:maven {:repositories {"custom" {...}}}` map.